# Ajax call returns internal 500 error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to execute an ajax call to the server but I seem to have no luck I keep getting back on the console an error 500 Internal server error.This is my ajax call:

```
    $("body").on("click", "#ok", function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-bookid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ProductEditor/DeleteBook",
        type:"POST",
        data: { bookId: parseInt(id) },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

And this is the C# code I am trying to call:

```
public ActionResult DeleteBook(int bookId)
{
   bookRepository.DeleteBook(bookId);
   return RedirectToAction("Books", "ProductManager");
}
```

While trying to debug I have noticed that the DeleteBook method is not even called.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** I have added the [HttpPost] attribute but it still does not work

Comment: add [HttpPost] above your controller action

Comment: have you decorated your method with [HttpPost]

Comment: The AJAX call is fine. As the message states, it's a server error, so check your server logs.

Comment: you may have a duplicate function in the backend or some syntex error

Comment: This error will show itself as soon as you do something on error handling. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653712/asp-net-mvc-3-500-error-logging-not-working-on-server) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464531/how-do-i-use-application-error-in-asp-net-mvc) how to catch errors.

Comment: use fiddler to see what has logged along with 500 internal server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information, it's not easy to tell you what you are doing wrong.

However, the `error` function callback for the jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function takes three parameters:

(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ProductEditor/DeleteBook",
    type:"POST",
    data: { bookId: parseInt(id) },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The third parameter, `errorThrown` will have the HTTP response text for the call to `/ProductEditor/DeleteBook`.  I would suggest looking at what errorThrown is showing, as well as possibly running the entire program in debug mode.

Perhaps `var id = $(this).attr("data-bookid");` is incorrect, and the value of id is being set to `undefined`?

Also, you can use the Network tab in the F12 Development Tools in IE or Chrome, Firebug in Firefox, or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug ajax calls.  You can watch the ajax request being sent to the server as well as the response from the server in order to see whether the correct data (`bookId`) is being sent in the correct format (JSON) and what the response is from the server

Comment: I also want to add you should be handling errors in your MVC actions, as @CodeCaster indicating in his comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your **WebMethod** must be **static**

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static ActionResult DeleteBook(int bookId) 
{    
     bookRepository.DeleteBook(bookId);    
     return RedirectToAction("Books", "ProductManager"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add HttpPost to your method and try

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteBook(int bookId)
{
   bookRepository.DeleteBook(bookId);
   return RedirectToAction("Books", "ProductManager");
}
```

Comment: I added it but still the method does not get called

Comment: Post the Error message you are getting with 500